# Is it safe to add values to OperationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage?

Tags: .net, wcf, authorization

I'm working on a WCF service that uses authorization tokens, where a token resolves to a username.  Access is an all-or-nothing kind of thing: people with a valid token should be able to do anything, and people without a valid token should get rejected.

I've set up an authorization manager like this:

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        var query = operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties.Via.Query;
        var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        var token = parameters["token"];

        if (TokenIsValid(token)) {
            var username = GetUsername(token);
            operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties.Add("username", username);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }         
    }
}
```

thinking that I'll access this value later using `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties["username"];`

My question is, can I trust this technique?  Would it be possible for a user to spoof a value in `RequestMessage.Properties`, or is this only used internally in the WCF service classes?  Is there a better place to store data so it can't be manipulated by a user?

Comment: Why are you trying to get username that way, if you are after the user that is calling your service you can get it straight away from operation context, without your client passing it in. And no you can't trust it because anyone can fake it if you are looking at the request message properties. :)

Comment: @Bravo11 Good question.  I could do the token-to-username resolution in each service method and it wouldn't be much different.  At the moment, the token is the only way to get the user calling the service, because we're not using Windows authentication.

Comment: so you are using cert i assume?